# google_tag_manager from within the browser console?

Tags: google-tag-manager

I have enabled the {{Random Number}} variable within GTM.

How can I grab and view the last generated random number from within the browsers DevTools console window?

For example:
`window.google_tag_manager[{{GTM-XXXX}}].dataLayer.get('{{Random Number}}')`

Why does that not work?